# how to Avoid multiple time server side hits while using jQuery FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, fullcalendar

I am using jQuery FullCalendar for bind events in calendar, and all the events are being fetched from database,the issue which i am facing is, when ever i am click on prev/next  in the calendar its again and again hitting the database which is actually not needed.even i cant use any session management in my existing sites.thanks for help in advance.

below is the sample code.

**Jquery:-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#idevents').click(function () {
                getEvents();
            });
        });

        function getEvents() {
            var CalLoading = true;
            $('#bootstrapModalFullCalendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: '',
                    center: 'prev title next',
                    right: ''
                },
                lazyFetching: true,
                eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
                    $("#eventInfo").html(event.description);
                    $("#eventLink").attr('href', event.url);
                    $("#eventContent").dialog({
                        modal: true,
                        title: event.title
                    });

                    return false;
                },
                events: '../Home/GetEvents/'
            });
        }
</script>
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div class="clearfix" id="bootstrapModalFullCalendarContainer"></div>
```

**Serverside code to get the list of events:-**

```
public JsonResult GetEvents()
        {
            var ApptListForDate = Events.LoadAlldataInDateRange();
            var eventList = from e in ApptListForDate
                            select new
                            {
                                title = e.EventName,
                                description = "<table><tr><td>Date:</td><td>"+e.DateTime+"</td></tr><tr><td>Time:</td><td>"+e.Time+"</td></tr><tr><td>Venue:</td><td>"+e.Venue+"</td></tr><tr><td>SPOC:</td><td>"+e.Spoc+"</td></tr><tr><td>Description:</td><td>"+e.description+"</td></tr><tr><td>HCL Attendees:</td><td>"+e.Attendees+"</td></tr></tr><tr><td>Speaker from HCL:</td><td>"+e.Speaker+"</td></tr></table>",
                                start=  e.plugginDate,
                                end = e.plugginDate,
                                allDay = false


                            };
            var rows = eventList.ToArray();
            return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: this `lazyFetching: true,` may be the cause

Comment: Thanks @madalin :- but i have checked with lazyFetching: true/false both the parameters and also removed lazyFetching and tried but its still hitting my server side code.

Comment: from what i see the full calendar doesn't normally do ajax request, so i think you trigger the click event `#idevents`

Comment: yes right, click event is getting triggered when i am clicking on the link  with id "#idevents", but its also hitting server side while clicking on prev/next  available in calendar.